# Password Confirmation Validation when origin changes

Tags: angularjs, validation, coffeescript, angularjs-directive

So, I need a validator that will check to make sure my `password_confirmation` field matches my `password` field. I ended up with the following directive:

**Directive**

```
@app.directive 'matches', ->
  require: 'ngModel', #Needed for validation bits
  scope: { matched_value: '=matches' } #Looks up the value of the scope element we're matching against and keeps it bound
  link: (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) ->
    ctrl.$parsers.unshift (view_value) -> #Add a new parser that updates the validity
      ctrl.$setValidity(elem.attr('name'), view_value == scope.matched_value)
```

**Form**

```
<form name="form">
  <input ng-model="new_user.password" name="password">
  <input ng-model="password_confirmation" name="password_confirmation" matches="new_user.password">
</form>
```

This works fine when the user uses the form from top to bottom. However, if they go on to change the `password` after they've filled in the `password_confirmation` then it doesn't become invalid like it should.

My first stab looked added a `$watch`er to the matches directive, but I can't seem to get the correct value of the new `password_confirmation` input.

**Directive w/ Watcher (CoffeeScript)**

```
@app.directive 'matches', ->
  require: 'ngModel', 
  scope: { matched_value: '=matches' }
  link: (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) ->
    ctrl.$parsers.unshift (view_value) ->
      ctrl.$setValidity(elem.attr('name'), view_value == scope.matched_value)
    scope.$watch attrs['watches'], ->
      ctrl.$setValidity(elem.attr('name'), ctrl.$view_value == scope.matched_value)
```

But `ctrl.$view_value` is always undefined, leading me to believe that I'm doing this wrong.

How would I get the actual value? Is this the correct way to set up this sort of inverse relationship? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

https://github.com/wongatech/angular-confirm-field is a good project for this.

Example here http://wongatech.github.io/angular-confirm-field/

The code below shows 2 input fields with the implemented functionality

```
<input ng-model="email" name="my-email" />
<input ng-confirm-field ng-model="emailconfirm" confirm-against="email" name="my-email-confirm"/>
```

This directive differs from other implementations in the way it uses $parsers and $watch to ensure the model property is only updated when the view value is valid.

Answer (score 1):

You can watch both elements from the one directive.  Pass a function to watch.  Each digest, it will compare values instead of only when the one element changes.

```
.directive('match', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            match: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            scope.$watch(function() {
                var modelValue = ctrl.$modelValue || ctrl.$$invalidModelValue;
                return (ctrl.$pristine && angular.isUndefined(modelValue)) || scope.match === modelValue;
            }, function(currentValue) {
                ctrl.$setValidity('match', currentValue);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

With `(ctrl.$pristine && angular.isUndefined(ctrl.$modelValue))`, it will not add the error until the field is touched or something is in it (pre-filled).

More info: https://github.com/TheSharpieOne/angular-input-match

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/TheSharpieOne/Wnv8u/

For version 1.3.x of angular, the new validation pipeline works best, here is the version for angular 1.3.x

```
.directive('match', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            match: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            scope.$watch('match', function(pass){
                ctrl.$validate();
            });
            ctrl.$validators.match = function(modelValue){
                return (ctrl.$pristine && (angular.isUndefined(modelValue) || modelValue === "")) || modelValue === scope.match;
            };
        }
    };
});
```